# Combinations - The number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r persons such that each person gets at least one object

Tags: combinatorics

So I came across this question and was unable to figure out the logic. Question -

**Statement-1:**
The number of ways of distributing 10 identical balls in 4 distinct boxes such that no box is empty is C(9,3) ​

**Statement-2:**
The number of ways of choosing any 3 places from 9 different places is C(9,3)

According to my answer key and the internet, both these statements are true. But I don't understand how.

Shouldn't the number of ways of distributing 10 identical balls in 4 distinct boxes such that no box is empty be C(10, 4) instead of C(9,3) ?​

Comment: This is an example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics); we are distributing 3 bars within 9 spaces between stars.

Comment: So essentially you're counting the number of integer solutions to
$$
(x_1+1) + (x_2+1) + \ldots + (x_{r-1}+1) + (x_r +1 ) = n
$$
which is the same as
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_r = n - r
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it that way: we lay down the ten balls in a line, now instead of putting them into 4 boxes we place three walls anywhere between those balls. This is equivalent to putting them into 4 boxes(2 walls or a wall and one end of the line form a "box".) Now as we assume the 4 boxes to be nonempty we do not want to walls to be next to each other without a ball between them and similary we do not want a wall at an end of the line. (|....|....|.. would not be allowed, whereas .|..|....|... is legit.) Now how many possibilities are there to place these walls? Well thats simple: we have 9 places(anywhere between the ten balls without the ends) and we have to place 3 walls, so the answer is $\binom{9}{3}$.